# Disc brake freezes up

Tags: brakes

The rear brake freezes up on my bicycle.  Never the front which I don't understand.  It is not that cold out either @20 degrees.  This is the first bike I have owned that has disc brakes.  My cantilever brakes never did this.

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information if we're to help you. For example: cable or hydraulic brakes; degrees C or F (obvious if you mean "freeze" literally); do the pads freeze to the discs locking the wheel, or are the does the lever not move? Is there snow/surface water present (this could explain back but not front as did is flicked into the back wheel/cables much more than the front)?

Comment: This is reasonably common with cable rim brakes, especially in the presence of grime (where the solution is usually to replace the cable and clean the brake + pivots). How does the cable react if you pull on it?

Comment: As it stands this question is likely to be closed because it lacks details.  Please use the Edit function to provide further information, and photos if they help explain the problems you're having.  Is the bike stored outside in the weather?   How old is the bike?  Does the rear brake cable show shiny silver or is it dull and rusting ?

Answer (score 6):

Are you using cable disc brakes? If so, is the rear caliper mounts to  the chain stay or the seat stay?  If it is the chain stay, the brake cable will likely dip down then run along the chain stay (see picture).  If the brake caliper doesn't not have a cable boot (most systems except Avid BB7) water can enter and get trapped in the cable housing.  If there is water in the cable housing, when it is freezing out your rear brake will quite literally freeze up.

[image]

This won't happen on the front brake because the cable housing is vertical so water will continually drain out.  This is also true for rear cable disc brakes mounted on the chain stay.

#### Solutions

If you bring your bike inside to thaw, then you can hang the bike rear wheel down to let the water drain from rear brake the housing.  If this doesn't fix the problem (water cohesion may retain some water in the system) you can also try evacuating the water with oil (then the drain the oil out of the housing to reduce the amount of dirt that will be attracted).  Finally, failing all else, you can replace the cable and housing (but riding in the rain will send you right back to where you were when it freezes again).

This is an unfortunate side effect of mounting a brake caliper on the lower (chain) stay and not fully sealing the cable housing. As an aside, mounting on the chain stay makes it easier to mount rear pannier racks, which is a much more difficult task when mounting the caliper on the seat stay.

Comment: My rear brake looks almost exactly like the one pictured.  I will hang the bike rear wheel down to drain the water out.   Is there a manufacture of a rubber boot that could slip over that cable?

Comment: @madisondan - That boot came with the BB7 brake caliper, most other calipers I have seen do not appear to be designed to directly take a boot.  If you have BB7 caliper you can get order a replacement boot.  If your have a different brand of caliper (a picture would help) I am less certain of your options.  I have seen TRP calipers with boots as an OEM component from a big brand, but I have no idea  how well they seal nor their general availability.  The BB7 caliper itself has a ridge that the boot fits over onto making the system effectively water tight.

Comment: I appreciate the help you've given me.  Same thing the last two days has happened.   Take it out of the basement and ride for @ five minutes and brake lever freezes up solid.   I will store the bike rear wheel down to see if I can get the water out of the cable housing.  Before the cold hit we did get pounded with rain so I can see how water would have gotten into the cable housing.  I cannot figure out how to upload a picture here so I apologize for that.  The caliper just says zoom on it.

Comment: @madisondan - Water cohesion may still be retaining enough water that it binds the cable in freezing conditions (recall that water expands when frozen).  You are starting to run out of options.  You can try disassembling the rear cable/cable housing and running oil through the housing to evacuate the remaining water or you may need to replace the cable/cable housing assembly.  Without a way to seal the system you will be back to square one the next time it rains before freezing temperature.

Comment: @madisondan - I had this exact scenario happen to me last year and I ended up changing the brake calipers to ones that could create a sealed system.  So far no problems this year.  And we have had one of the biggest rain falls in 10 years, followed by freezing weather.

Comment: If water in the cable housing is believed to be the cause, one might consider dripping full-strength auto antifreeze into the housing.  (I *think* that the antifreeze should be "compatible" with the housing material, and actually serve as a lubricant, but don't hold me to it.)  Medicinal glycerin or something similar could be used as an alternative to the auto antifreeze.  There is also an antifreeze in a small squirt can sold for locks.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Interesting idea!  You could probably just drip some in from the brake caliper end.  Just don't hang the bike or you will get antifreeze draining out from a cable housing end.

Comment: @Rider_X - Yeah, you'd want to keep it away from the disk and pads.  But anywhere else it should be harmless.

Comment: No problems this morning.  But it is above freezing.  @34 degrees

Comment: @madisondan - which is consistent with the ice formation hypothesis.  We will have to wait to the next sub-zero before we can get confirmation on whether or not the actions taken have helped.

Comment: Above freezing today and rained all day.  Bike is downstairs with three drops of water so far dripped out of the housing.  Next week will be in the single digits for temps.  I will not bring this up and down to the basement every night.  (We live in a @110 year old house with low head height basement, steep steps, etc.) It's harder to bring the bike downstairs then riding in the cold!)   If it is water getting into the cable then I have to seal that open end somehow.  Correct?

Comment: @madisondan if you do not clarify your question (e.g., temperature scale - 20 degrees centigrade is very warm) this question will be put on hold and forgotten)